# Removing a class from parent container and then adding it back from a child

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I'm removing a class on click from a parent container which is working fine:

```
$(".no-close").click(function(){
   $(".nav-overlay").removeClass("slide-in-overlay");
});
```

But, when I make a child element to put the class back on the main container it doesn't work:

```
$(".right menu li").click(function(){
   $(".nav-overlay").addClass("slide-in-overlay");
});
```

Any idea on what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you want to add to parent the use this reference like `$(this).parent()` or $(this).closest(".parentid")` this ensure you add to its parent only and not other element.  from your code it looks like it should work and it must be something else that is preventing it. please share more information maybe a sample HTML page help you.

Comment: @SumitGupta You mean `$(this).closest(".parentClass")`

Comment: Please provide your HTML so we can understand your DOM.

Comment: See [menu element compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu#browser_compatibility)

Comment: @freedomn-m so likely a typo and it should have been `.menu`

Comment: @mplungjan that's what I was thinking

Comment: @SumitGupta, @mplungjan, @Mateen, @freedomn-m - thank you so much for your feedback. `e.stopPropagation();` worked for me in the end.

Comment: Glad you found your solution.  Click events "bubble up".  Knowing the HTML layout would have likely allowed someone to spot that for you.